# If two objects collide at the same speed differential, does the force exerted change if one of the objects is moving?

Tags: potential-energy, collision

Using the illustration below as an example, if the black ball moving at 100 MPH collided with the stationary red ball, would it exert more force than the black ball moving at 200 MPH colliding with the red ball moving at 100 MPH in the same direction?

[image: Collision Example]

Comment: Or consider what happens in the center-of-mass frame, the easiest frame to do the physics in...

Answer (score 1):

**No** in both cases force will be same.

## Explanation

since no balls have acceleration and all newton's laws are valid in uniformly moving bodies, so in second case if we go in frame of red ball, we can apply all newton's laws. In frame of red ball in both cases velocity of black ball is constant so force will also be constant. However the effect of force might be a little bit different due to motion in second case (still it will result in same change in momentum of red/black ball individually)

## An example

suppose both balls have same mass $m$. Now since they are interacting for a very small time we can assume time of interaction to be constant and just compare impulses between them.

since both balls have same mass, after collision in first case final situation will be (assuming no energy loss)

$$v_{black} = 0 MPH ;$$
$$  v_{red} = 100 MPH$$

$$\implies impulse = m (100-0)$$

in second case
$$v_{black} = 100 MPH ;$$
$$  v_{red} = 200 MPH$$
$$\implies impulse = m (200-100)$$

as you can see in both cases impulse and approx time of interaction is same so force will also be same.

Answer (score 1):

> would it exert more force than the black ball moving at 200 MPH colliding with the red ball moving at 100 MPH in the same direction?

No, the force does not depend on the velocity of the center of mass, just on the relative velocity. To see this, start with the equations for an [inelastic collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inelastic_collision). $$v_a=\frac{C_r m_b (u_b-u_a)+m_a u_a+m_b u_b}{m_a+m_b}$$
$$v_b=\frac{C_r m_a (u_a-u_b)+m_a u_a+m_b u_b}{m_a+m_b}$$ Next, define the relative initial velocity and the velocity of the center of mass $$u_r=u_a-u_b$$
$$u_c=\frac{m_a u_a+m_b u_b}{m_a+m_b}$$ Finally define the change in momentum, which is the impulse/force $$\Delta p_a=m_a (v_a-u_a)$$  $$\Delta p_b=m_b (v_b-u_b)$$

Now, we have 6 equations, so we can use 4 to eliminate $v_a$, $v_b$, $u_a$, and $u_b$ to get expressions for $\Delta p_a$ and $\Delta p_b$ in terms of $u_r$ and $u_c$. When we do that we get $$\Delta p_a=-\frac{(C_r+1) m_a m_b }{m_a+m_b}u_r$$  $$\Delta p_b=\frac{(C_r+1) m_a m_b }{m_a+m_b}u_r$$

As you can see, the change in momentum depends only on $u_r$ and not on $u_c$. So as long as the relative velocity is kept constant (and the masses etc.), it doesn't matter what is the velocity of the center of mass.

Answer (score 0):

First, be careful about asking about forces in momentum problems. The change of momentum(impulse) may be the same in two situations, but the force may differ because:

$$\int{Fdt} = \Delta p $$
Or if you're not familiar with calculus
$$F_{avg}\Delta t = \Delta p $$

To guarantee the same force you need to guarantee that both momentum change and the time of action of the force(the impulse time) is the same. In your example, if the black ball and the red ball are, say, two golf balls, and in the second scenario, they are the same golf balls, then you can reasonably say that the contact time is the same, thus the force will be equal for the same change of momentum. But lets say you change the red ball for a cotton ball on the second scenario. EVEN if the mass of the cotton ball and the velocity are the same as your portrayed, you can't say that the contact time is the same, therefore can't say that the force is the same

Now, answering your question having all these warnings in mind: No, the forces are the same. The momentum change depends only on the relative velocities of the particles. Since both of them have initial constant velocity, you can choose a reference point that has the same constant velocity of any of them(Say, the red ball), and in the reference of the red ball in both cases the black ball is moving towards it with 100MPH, the laws of motion are the same in all inertial frames, so the collisions will be identical, providing the same change of momentum for each ball(conserving the total amount)

PS: You can also generalize this result by taking the reference point to be the center of mass(cm). In this case of two-body problems, the velocity of the cm will always be constant, and in any case, the Forces will only depend on the relative motion of the particles.